# How to get more than 3ch audio input from getUserMedia() on javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, google-chrome, audio

I'd like to get more than 3ch audio input from getUserMedia() on javascript.

I use Google chrome.
I connected audio interface which has more than 3ch audio input with Windows10,
using USB cable.
I tried to get the sound from the audio interface using "navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);" on javascript.
I can get 1 and 2ch audio input.
But I can't get more than 3ch audio input from the audio interface.

Digital mixer software attached the audio interface can get more than 3ch audio input.

I think that getUserMedia() get the sound from default Windows audio driver.
So I can get 1 and 2ch audio input.

I heard that audio driver of mac OS is USB AUDIO CLASS 2.0.
I tried it on mac OS.
I can get 1 and 2ch audio input.
But I can't get more than 3ch audio input using getUserMedia().

How can I get more than 3ch audio input from the audio interface on javascript?

I think that if getUserMedia() get the sound from ASIO driver,I can do that.
But I'm not sure how to use ASIO driver on getUserMedia() on javascript.

If you know something,please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let me start off by saying that even if you do get multichannel (3+ channels) input recording working with JS in a browser, I would be suprised to see it working well without at least very high latency. That being said, it's always worth having a go and learning in the process.

## Chromium's [audio_input_controller.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/media/audio/audio_input_controller.cc)

If you check the source code for Chromium (Chrome is built ontop of), the file [audio_input_controller.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/media/audio/audio_input_controller.cc) states:

```
Line 31 >> const int kMaxInputChannels = 3;
```

Which suggests that if you wanted to go any higher than 3 channels I don't think its possible. This is assuming that Chrome hasn't built ontop of this further and added more channel input support, however I have not seen anything so far supporting higher than stereo channel input directly through Chrome. This was in the GitHub folder under no specific OS so I assume it's used on all desktop platforms.

## [media.getusermedia.channels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

As stated in the [MediaDevices.getUserMedia() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia):

> The preference media.getusermedia.channels lets you control the
>   maximum number of channels to be captured; a value of 0, the default,
>   tells getUserMedia() to capture all of the available, supported,
>   channels.

So to test the maximum number of input channels actually supported, I would set this parameter to 0 and see how many buffers of audio are actually returned - this way you will know for sure your system's channel limit.

## Summary

I am not sure what the target of your application is, but in terms of multichannel input via the browser there is no alternative other than to wait until the browser itself supports multichannel input. Like you said, your DAW can access more than 3ch input because this is a compiled piece of software running seperate to the browser, and has access to all of the system level information (i.e. your sound card hardware and all of its communication).

## Recommendation

I am not sure on your level of programming experience, but for this kind of thing you would normally use C++ (or another language but C++ is the go-to for audio generally) to build an application seperate to your browser and run it on your PC. To get the multichannel audio input in C++ you would then use a framework like [JUCE](https://juce.com/) or [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/).

You could create a process that sends the audio from your desktop to the webpage locally if you were committed to using JS in a web browser. This could be done in C++ or if you are more new to this maybe Python with [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) would be simpler to get started.

Also, if you are familiar/haven't been introduced to [Electron.js,](https://electronjs.org/) you could also build a compiled application (i.e. a .exe on windows) which would have access to all of the audio channels since it's not running in a browser, but just using the browser to interperet the javascript. I found this [binding for portaudio](https://github.com/AudioNet/node-core-audio) to use within Electron.js that should support multichannel input. That way you could write a desktop application using just JavaScript/HTML/CSS and have multichannel audio input!

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
We can't get sound of multichannel input on Web browser until until the browser itself supports multichannel input,right?
OK,I'll try it on native application which I'll develop.